# Writing to same ArrayList from several methods at the same time

Tags: java, arraylist

I have several data listeners, which may receive datasets roughly at the same time. They will iterate datasets and store data to the same `ArrayList` by using its method `add()`. Could this potentially cause any issues of some data items not being stored?

Comment: Are these all on the same thread? Are you removing any items?

Comment: This is all in the Javadoc. [`ArrayList` 'is not synchronized.  If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it *must* be synchronized externally.'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: These are updated from several Firebase result listeners - I'm not sure if they run on UI or separate threads. Not removing any items. Just want to join results, that I get by using several different filters.

Comment: So tell us what exactly 'roughly at the same time means'. In any case if you don't know it's single-threaded, you have to assume it isn't, and defend accordingly.

Comment: User may select 1 to 10 selections and accordingly 1 to 10 Firebase queries will be launched at the same time to retrieve these subsets from large dataset. Depending on the size of each subset, I guess these will be delivered within several seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use synchronized block in this case :

```
synchronized (this){
    // ...
}
```

You can find a good examples here [Synchronized](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html)

Comment: Any similar resource in English?

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` is not synchronized. From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads
>   access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the
>   threads modifies the list structurally, it *must* be synchronized
>   externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or
>   deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array;
>   merely setting the value of an element is not a structural
>   modification.)

You can use [synchronizedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)) for this

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList(...));
```